# NServiceBus Outbox exactly once processing

Tags: nservicebus, outbox-pattern, transactional-outbox

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/outbox/), it says:

> - Due to possible failures, a given message may be sent multiple times. For example, if an exception is thrown in step 3 (failure to
>   update outbox storage) the message will be read from outbox storage
>   again and will be sent again. **As long as the receiving endpoints use
>   the outbox feature, these duplicates will be handled by the
>   deduplication in phase 1, step 2.**

I was wondering how exactly this deduplication phase works when the transport is rabbitmq and the outbox persistence is sql server. It is not possible to have a transaction between these two so once you have successfully handled your rabbitmq message, it seems to me the sql server call to update the outbox as 'message delivered to queue' can still fail, resulting in handling the rabbitmq message more than once on the receiving endpoint in case the sending endpoint sends again in the meantime?

I feels like I'm making a reasoning error because I don't fully understand how it works.

Any insights?

Comment: Well with outbox u have 2 phases. First one is persisting message in your database "OutboxData" , after that other services does the publishing and sets flag "Dispatched" to true if it was successful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the SQL call to set Dispatched = true can still fail, and then the RabbitMQ message would be handled again. But the next time it's handled, before invoking the message handler it will `select from Outbox where MessageId = <id>` and see that the message handler was already successfully invoked and the results committed to the database the last time around, and so it will skip over the message handler and go directly to the dispatch phase.

So even if there was an odd problem with the SQL server where 100 duplicates got created because you couldn't set Dispatched on that table, the receiving endpoint running deduplication would receive all 100 messages but after the first one be going "Seen it, seen it, seen it, seen it…"

Comment: How does the message handler indicates that the message was already successfully invoked? I'm sure that I'm still missing something here, I don't understand how that can be atomically committed when the outbox is on sql server and the transport is rabbitmq

Comment: RabbitMQ is not involved in the transaction. RabbitMQ doesn't support transactions that span something else than RabbitMQ. We first commit the SQL transaction (which should include the Outbox row and your business data) and then ack the message in RabbitMQ. If the RabbitMQ ack fails, the message will be processed again. But NServiceBus will validate in the database if the message has been processed already. If it has, it won't do that again.

Comment: What can happen, is that a send/publish can happen several times as well. But because we store all outgoing messages in the database as well, if something fails and the message is send multiple times, those messages will always be send using the exact same message identifier. On the other side, Outbox will then duplicate the same way.

Comment: NServiceBus takes care of all of this. Just do `EnableOutbox()` and it takes care of everything behind the scenes.

Comment: @PieterVermeersch the message handler indicates it was successfully invoked by not throwing an exception.